# MS SQL/SSRS Query Parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services

This is going to be a simple one, I just can't figure it out.

```
select * from table
```

Returns:

```
|Item|Ordernumber|Color
|apple|2|Green|
|orange|2|yellow|
|apple|3|Red|
```

I want to filter on color

```
select * from table 
where color = Green
```

I get, as expected

```
|Item|Ordernumber|Color
|apple|2|Green|
```

I would like to show all items for the same order number IF the order contains any items with color Green

```
|Item|Ordernumber|Color
|apple|2|Green|
|orange|2|yellow|
```

I am creating a parameter in SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

You can first get the order number from the inner query (where color is green) and `join` it to the original table.

```
select item, t.ordernumber, color 
from table t join
(select ordernumber from table 
where color = 'Green') x
on x.ordernumber = t.ordernumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a parameter Color and put the parameter filter instead of hardcoding the color in the below code:-

```
select item, ordernumber, color 
from table where ordernumber in 
(select distinct ordernumber from table 
 where color = 'Green')
```